# laravel Eloquent where clause

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to do get all the users from a specific country via Eloquent.

The problem is that I get all the record, the where clause doesn't work.

```
$res = User::with(array('country' => function($query) {
          $query->where('country', '=', 'salope');
       }))->get();
```

Following this pattern from the laravel documentation

```
$users = User::with(array('posts' => function($query)
{
    $query->where('title', 'like', '%first%');
}))->get();
```

My models :

```
class User extends SentryUserModel {
    public function country() {

        return $this->belongsTo('country','country_id');
    }
}
class Country extends Eloquent {
    public function users() {

        return $this->hasMany('users');
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Why not `->where('country_id', $country->id)` ?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: No errors, just all the record. I'd like to filter them with a where clause

Comment: What is the fields in `country` table. ( or table associated with Country model ). Does it have field named `country`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found what I was looking for with laravel 4.1 version.
My question was not formulated correctly. I wanted to query a relationship.

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('comments', function($q)
{
    $q->where('content', 'like', 'foo%');

})->get();
```

so with my exemple:

```
 $res = User::whereHas('country', function($q) {
        $q->where('country', 'salope');
       })->get();
```

[Documentation link](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations)

Answer (score 2):

If you want the users for a particular country you need something like that.

```
$users = Country::whereCounty('salope')->users;
dd($users);
```

Where `users` is an eloquent `Collection` and you loop over that `Collection` and display the users. If you would like to continue building your query based on your users use `users()` and keep chaining, for example:

```
$users = Country::whereCounty('salope')->users()->whereBanned(0)->get(); // Or something
dd($users);
```

Comment: when I do $users = Country::where('country','salope')->users It says Undefined property

Comment: add the `$with` property in your `Country` model like so `public $with = array('users')` to eager load the relationship and try again the above example

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are retrieving all the users and then limiting only the countries those users can have.  So you are going to end up with all the users still, and not just the ones that belong to Salope.

I think the solution is to go about this backwards.

```
$country = Country::where('name', 'salope')->with('users')->first();

foreach($country->users as $user)
{
    echo $user->username;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$matchThese = ['title' => post('title'), 'slug' => post('slug')];
return Blog::where($matchThese)->get();
```

Something like this works too

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me as of Laravel 5.6

*I needed to create a relation for users with their roles. The relations has a pivot key using the user_roles tables that is linked to the role table.*

**In my User model**

```
public function role(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Roles', 'user_roles','user_id','role_id');
    }
```

Then, I created a static function in the **User model**

```
  public static function withRole($role){
        $members = self::whereHas('role',function($q) use($role){
            $q->where('name', '=', $role);
        })->get();
       return $members;
    }
```

Note the `use($role)` usage in the function.

I can then call this method with :

```
$members = User::withRole('the_role_name');
```

Hope this helps someone !